# SSL Enabling Problem: Tomcat in Windows 7

Tags: windows, windows-7, ssl

I downloaded Tomcat 7.08 Windows Service Installer and installed it.
I edited the server.xml to enable https connector port @ 8443
               
I already created the certificate and key pair using the keytool.

keytool -genkey -alias techtracer -keypass ttadmin -keystore techtracer.bin -storepass ttadmin

i started the server then, and tried https://localhost:8443/ but it was not showing anything. Firefox had shown "connected to localhost..." and nothing more.
I cant load any pages in https.

My System: **Windows 7 64-bits / 4GB RAM /JDK_JRE 6/ Tomcat 7.08/ Firefox 3.6**

Can Any one tell me what is the problem with the SSL in my system.?.Any way to fix this?
Thanks

Mr.k

Comment: I suggest this question and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4966441/ssl-enabling-problem-tomcat-in-windows-7 be collapsed into one.

Answer (score 4):

Solution: Update the `server.xml` file as follows:

```
<Connector port="8443" 
protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol"
SSLEnabled="true"               
maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true" 
keystoreFile="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\keystore\.keystore"
keystorePass="changeit"
clientAuth="false" 
sslProtocol="TLS" />
```

Please note that I changed the protocol from `"HTTP/1.1"` to `"org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol"` This should fix the problem.

Comment: resolved issue on my PC

Answer (score 1):

Same system, same configuration, same problem but with Tomcat 6. My solution was to switch to 32bit version of Tomcat. I think this is an issue related to 64bit distributions.

Answer (score 0):

seems like you have to configure your TOMCAT to work with SSL (in addition to all the things that are written above)

have a look [here](http://www.itworld.com/development/80705/how-enable-https-tomcat).
In addition, you might need to make another change in your settings.xml (tomcat configuration) and delete the line that refers to the APR listener.

Hope this helps...

Ohad